# plot black scholes option price in r

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot the Black & Scholes European call option price in the same graph in which I plotted the European call payoff.

Unfortunately, my code does not work.

```
#plot the call payoff
payoff.call <- function(S) sapply(S, function(S) max(c(S-K,0))) #payoff 

K <- 50 #set the strike price

curve(payoff.call, 0, 100, main = "Long Call Option Payoff function", 
      col = "blue", lty = 1, lwd = 1,xlab = "S", ylab = expression(f(S))) 

#plot the B&S prices on the same graph
fair_value <- function(S) sapply(S, function(S) S*pnorm((log(S/K) + (r + 0.5*sigma^2)*tau)/(sigma*sqrt(tau))) - K*exp(-r*(tau))*pnorm((log(S/K) + (r + 0.5*sigma^2)*tau)/(sigma*sqrt(tau)))- sigma*sqrt(tau))

tau <- 1/360 #set the time to maturity
r <- 0.12 #set the interest rate
sigma <- 0.3 #set the vola

curve(fair_value, 0, 100, col = "black", add= TRUE)
```

What I got is a graph in which the payoff is shown as expected, but I couldn't see the curve of the B&S prices.

Comment: Actually your codes are working well. But the graphs are overlapping. If you set `r=100` (just for creating difference) and rerun the codes, you will understand the issue.

Comment: @maydin thanks, if you can answer with a cleaner (easier to read) code (instead of using sapply) I'll accept your anwser!